# Symfony2 Integer field validation - Warning: NumberFormatter::parse(): Number parsing failed

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

Piece of my code:

```
$builder
        ->add('year', 'integer', array(
            'attr' => array(
                ....
            ),
```

Everything is ok, validation passed, but I have a little problem:

When I'm changing input type from "number" to "text" (directly in front, via console, on the server side is still a "number"), this exception appears before calling a validation (error is inside line with `$form->handleRequest($request);` code). I want to have a safe application without any errors, but this is very annoying^^

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean "directly in front, via console"? How are you trying to change from number to text?

Comment: My bad, not exactly a console^^  Firebug -> "HTML" tab :P

Comment: Are you trying to change an entity field from integer to text? Then you should check that there are no numeric validations on the entity or the form type class.

Comment: Yep. But i want to know, why this is not working^^

Comment: And I want to have only integer value (not string). So when I'm using a type="integer" constraint it fails (integer type field is required). I know, that I can use a regex constraint (and probably it will be the best solution)

Comment: mmm yes in that case I reconmend you to keep evertything in text and implement a regex in the field and also in the entity to ensure your data integrity.

Comment: And I will do that. But still I want to know, why this exception appears^^

Comment: Did you see this? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-validation "Calling $form->isValid() is a shortcut that asks the $task object whether or not it has valid data". Look at the data type validation on the entity. Maybe it helps to understand...

Comment: Yeah, I know... But type validation doesn't help^^